# Weblogic- WsdlParseFailedException -- Unable to parse WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, weblogic

I have a simple java web service and I deployed the earfile to Weblogic. Now when I click on ?WSDL to access the WSDL file, I get an error saying "**ERROR 403--Forbidden.** The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it."

And if I click on 'Test Client', it tells me that

> Unable to parse WSDL, http://localhost:7001/myWebService?WSDL failed
>   due to **weblogic.testclient.WsdlParseFailedException**

Does anyone know how to solve this? Or at least can you tell me what steps I can take to find what could be causing the issue? Thank you!

Comment: it's too broad of an issue to take a guess. please add the code you were trying so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

A 403 Forbidden error can also be caused by incorrect ownership or permissions on your web content files and folders. check the logs